# CMake not redirecting stderr with execute_process

Tags: cmake, stdout, stderr

I'm trying to redirect `stdout` and `stderr` to the same file using CMake. I'm using the `execute_process` option in CMake with the `ERROR_FILE` and `OUTPUT_FILE` option specified.

I'm successfully capturing the output, but the error is not there. What am I doing wrong?

File `CMakeLists.txt`

```
add_test(NAME test${ID}
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND}
    -DEXE=../examples/test${exampleID}
    -DID=${ID}
    -DARGS=${args}
    -P ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Tester.cmake
)
```

File `Tester.cmake`

```
separate_arguments( ARGS )
# Run the test
execute_process( 
    COMMAND "${EXE}" ${ARGS}
    ERROR_FILE test${ID}.out
    OUTPUT_FILE test${ID}.out
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifying the same file for both `OUTPUT_FILE` and `ERROR_FILE` has only recently been added in CMake 3.3. See [release notes](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/release/3.3.html).

As a work-around for earlier versions, use the options `OUTPUT_VARIABLE` and  `ERROR_VARIABLE` with the same variable and then write the contents of the variable to the file, e.g.:

```
execute_process( 
    COMMAND "${EXE}" ${ARGS}
    ERROR_VARIABLE _testOut
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE _testOut
)
file (WRITE "test${ID}.out" "${_testOut}")
```