# Executing bash commands from a CMake file

Tags: bash, cmake

I am having trouble understanding CMake. What I want to do is execute the following bash command during the build process:

`date +"%F %T" > timestamp`

This fetches the current date and writes it to a file. However, I cannot seem to reproduce this simple action using CMake commands.

Here are a few things that I've tried:

`execute_process(COMMAND "date +'%F %T' > timestamp")`

`add_custom_command(OUTPUT timestamp COMMAND date +"%F %T")`

`file(WRITE timestamp date +"%F %T")`

Neither seem to work. I almost wonder if they are even being executed at all.

I have a very limited knowledge of how CMake and its syntax, so I am probably doing things very wrong. I am hoping someone could point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: You can't use `>` in there... http://stackoverflow.com/a/31523634/2836621

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get cmake to create timestamp file after an actual build/link? (do nothing if executable hasn't changed)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13419255/how-to-get-cmake-to-create-timestamp-file-after-an-actual-build-link-do-nothin)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I think my main issue was the lack of quotes around my command arguments. Also, thanks to @Mark Setchell I realized I should be using `OUTPUT_VARIABLE` in lieu of `OUTPUT`

At any rate, here is the answer I arrived at:

```
execute_process (
    COMMAND bash -c "date +'%F %T'"
    OUTPUT_VARIABLE outVar
)
```

This stores the output of the bash command into the variable `outVar`

```
file(WRITE "datestamp" "${outVar}")
```

And this writes the contents of `outVar` to a file called "datestamp".

Answer (score 13):

Note -Using bash -c will also prep-end a new line to end of the variable which will cause make to complain depending on how you are using it

> build.make: *** missing separator.  Stop.

this should solve the above

```
execute_process(COMMAND  which grpc_cpp_plugin OUTPUT_VARIABLE GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN)
string(STRIP ${GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN} GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN)
message(STATUS "MY_VAR=${GRPC_CPP_PLUGIN}")
```

Comment: This is very important, or you will definitely run into *build.make: *** missing separator. Stop.* because of the newline character that will be appended.